# window.matchMedia is not a function error with tinyMCE react test

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am using tinyMCE in my project while testing the tinyMCE component.
I am facing the error

```
 window.matchMedia is not a function
```

in the import of `import 'tinymce/tinymce';`

in my test file, I tried to mock it with

```
beforeAll(() => {
server.listen();
Object.defineProperty(window, "matchMedia", {
    writable: true,
    value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
        matches: false,
        media: query,
        onchange: null,
        addListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
        removeListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
        addEventListener: jest.fn(),
        removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
        dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
    }))
  });
});
```

but still getting the same error.

How to mock so that the node_modules libs use the mock windows object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom.

```
If window.matchMedia() is executed directly in the tested file, Jest reports the same error. In this case, the solution is to move the manual mock into a separate file and include this one in the test before the tested file:
```

This means somewhere there is invocation of the `matchMedia` method but since you mocked it within a specific test file, it complains.

One way to handle this is to move this piece of code within a separate `setupJestMocks.js` and add that within the `setupFiles` of `jestConfig.js`. Details here https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array